# Does Camel Dynamic To (aka ToD) still need to be explicit?

Tags: dynamic, apache-camel

According to this [link](https://planet.jboss.org/post/apache_camel_2_16_released_top_10_highlights), Release 2.16 of Camel introduced the toD construct:

> Can now easily be done using toD
>
> .toD("freemarker://templateHome/${body.templateName}.ftl")
>
> ***We made to and toD separated on purpose. As the former allows Camel to
> optimize as it knows its a static endpoint, and the latter is dynamic.***
>
> The dynamic ***to*** is also supported in a few other EIPs such as WireTap,
> and in the rest-dsl.

toD is in enrich too.  Is it really still necessary to have to() and toD()?  Could to() determine if its static or dynamic and branch accordingly without the user having to be explicit in their code?

Answer (score 0):

There is yet an added-value of offering both possibilities.

When `to("direct:foo")` is used, Camel will check **on context boot time** that the target uri exists, and will throw an exception if this is not the case.

When using `toD("${headers.myDynamicUri}")`, Camel is obviously not able (at least not before run-time) to guess final uri. And so, you may have more "bad surprises" (eg invalid uris) than with regular to().

But you are right: considering that everything that to() can do, toD() can also do it, Camel could potentially "merge" both into a smart to()...

Anyway, keep also in mind what the doc says:

> When using dynamic computed endpoints with toD then you may compute a
> lot of dynamic endpoints, which results in an overhead of resources in
> use, by each dynamic endpoint uri, and its associated producer.